# Create a jar file from source folder with build.xml

Tags: java, ant, jar

I have download an API which has the following structure:

In the folder, there is a source folder and a build.xml file. How would I go about creating a jar out of this?

Comment: Unclear question. A jarfile is effectively a special kind of a zip Archive. So it can consist of the source and a build.xml. But I guess you want to compile the source, and package the classes, defined in your build.xml-file? Might need an ant-tag. Did you look into the build.xml, whether there is a jar-target?

Comment: First see what tasks the build file provides. You might want to check out some basic ant/java tutorials before going much further.

Comment: Sounds like [ant](http://ant.apache.org/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the build.xml file doesn't already have a target that creates a jar file, you can read about the *ant jar command* here:

- http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html

However, there's probably a good chance that the build file already does this for you.

You can run the build script by typing *ant* when you're in the directory that contains the build.xml file (after unpacking the jar).

Just for fun, here is an example of a *simple* ant target that compiles some code and creates a jar.

This target will compile every .java file in any folder named reports.

As you can see, most of the values are using variables defined elsewhere in the script, but hopefully you get the idea...

```
<target name="create-funky-jar" depends="some-other-funky-targets">
    <javac
      srcdir="${src.dir}"
      includes="**/reports/*.java"
      destdir="${build.classes.dir}"
      deprecation="${javac.deprecation}"
      source="${javac.source}"
      target="${javac.target}"
      includeantruntime="false">
      <classpath>
        <path path="${javac.classpath}:${j2ee.platform.classpath}"/>
      </classpath>
    </javac>

    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/SomeFunkyJar.jar"
         basedir="${build.classes.dir}"
         includes="**/reports/*.class"/>
  </target>
```

The above was just created by modifying a build script generated by NetBeans.

You can run the above target by adding it to a build.xml file and typing the following from the command line:

```
ant create-funky-jar
```

Note: You'll have to define all the variables for it to actually work.

Answer (score 0):

`build.xml` is a file used by ant and it could contain the procedure Ant should follow to build tha appropiate kind of file (like a `jar`).

I'd recommend reading something like [this guide](http://www.allapplabs.com/ant/installing_ant.htm) (The chapters called *Installing* and *Running*). Another option could be use Netbeans since it already has Ant and it has options to create a project from an existing `build.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

In the directory where the build.xml-file is, type

```
ant -p
```

Maybe you need to install ant first.

If there is a target to create a jar, chose that one, for example

```
ant jar
```